# creating twinkling effect using javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```
var stars = function() {

this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()* 1000)   ;

this.y = Math.floor(Math.random()* 900)   ;

this.radius = 2  ;

this.starColour = "gold";





  }

   var starNum = 20;
   var starry = new Array(starNum);

 for(var s = 0 ; s < 100 ; s++){

 starry[s] = new stars()
}


var starDraw = function() {


var starCanvas = document.getElementById("stars");

var starCtx = starCanvas.getContext("2d");
starCtx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 900);

for(i = 0; i < 100 ; i++){
  var star = starry[i];



  starCtx.fillStyle= "white";

starCtx.shadowBlur = 5;

starCtx.shadowColor = "white";
  starCtx.beginPath();





  // draw it
  starCtx.arc(star.x, star.y, star.radius,  Math.PI * 2, false);
  starCtx.stroke();
  starCtx.fill();


   }


}






   function starLoop(){ 

starDraw(); 
requestAnimationFrame(starLoop); 
}

 requestAnimationFrame(starLoop);
```

So I am trying to create a twinkling effect for the stars using only javascript and I can't figure out how to do it.
I have searched around and found no real answers up to now so I would appreciate if I could get an answer here. I am very new to coding so please take it easy on me.

Comment: Suggest using css to make this effect. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/psullivan6/ma6e78m0/

Answer (score 3):

A random star field. A little exaggerated, but easy to tone down (or up) if needed.

The important part is to avoid direct random values as most things in nature are not random but tend to fall close to a fixed point. This is call a gaussian distribution.  There are several ways to generate such random values.

```
// gRandom is far more likely to be near 0.5 than 1 or zero
var gRandom = (Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random()) / 4;

// or
// gRandom is more likely to be near zero than near 1
var gRandom = Math.random() * Math.random();
```

I use these method to set the sizes of stars (far more small stars than big) and create the colour and movement.

To try and get a more realistic effect I also move the stars by less than a pixel. This has the effect of changing the brightness but not look like movement.

Code has plenty of comments

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// function calls a callback count times. Saves typing out for loops all the time 
const doFor = (count, callback) => {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < count) {
    callback(i++)
  }
};
// creates a random integer between min and max. If min only given the between 0 and the value 
const randI = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => (Math.random() * (max - min) + min) | 0;
// same as above but as floats.
const rand = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
// creates a 2d point at x,y. If only x is a point than set to that point
const point = (x = 0, y) => {
  if (x.x && y === undefined) {return { x: x.x,y: x.y} }
  return {x,y: y === undefined ? 0 : y }
};
function ease (time, amount = 2) { return Math.pow(time % 1,amount) };
const clamp = (v, min = 1,max = min + (min = 0)) => v < min ? min : v > max ? max : v;




// stuff for stars
const skyColour = [10,30,50];
const density = 1000; // number of star per every density pixels
const colourChangeRate = 16; // Time in frames to change a colour
const stars = [];
const star = { // define a star
  draw() {
    this.count += 1; // integer counter used to triger color change every 16 frames
    if (this.count % colourChangeRate === 0) { // change colour ?
      // colour is a gaussian distrabution (NOT random) centered at #888
      var c = (Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random()) * 4;
      var str = "#";
      str += Math.floor(c * this.red).toString(16); // change color
      str += Math.floor(c * this.green).toString(16); // change color
      str += Math.floor(c * this.blue).toString(16); // change color
      

      this.col = str;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = this.col;
    // move star around  a pixel. Again its not random
    // but a gaussian distrabution. The movement is sub pixel and will only
    // make the stars brightness vary not look like its moving
    var ox = (Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random()) / 4;
    var oy = (Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random()) / 4;
    ctx.fillRect(this.pos.x + ox, this.pos.y + oy, this.size, this.size);
  }
}
// create a random star
// the size is caculated to produce many more smaller stars than big
function createStar(pos) {
  stars.push(Object.assign({}, star, {
    pos,
    col: "#ccc",
    count: randI(colourChangeRate),
    size: rand(1) * rand(1) * 2 + 0.5,
    red: 1-(rand(1) * rand(1) *rand(1)),  // reduces colour channels
    green: 1-(rand(1) * rand(1) *rand(1)), // but only by a very small amount
    blue: 1-(rand(1) * rand(1) *rand(1)),  // most of the time but occasional 
                                           // star will have a distinct colour
  }));
}

var starCount;
var skyGrad;

// render the stars
function mainLoop(time) {
  // resize canva if page size changes
  if (canvas.width !== innerWidth || canvas.height !== innerHeight) {
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    // create a new set of stars 
    stars.length = 0;
    // density is number of pixels one the canvas that has one star
    starCount = Math.floor((canvas.width * canvas.height) / density);
    // create the random stars;
    doFor(starCount, () => createStar(point(randI(canvas.width), randI(canvas.height))));
    skyGrad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,canvas.height);
    skyGrad.addColorStop(0,"black");
    doFor(100,(i)=>{
        var pos  = clamp(i/100,0,1);
        var col = ease(pos);
        skyGrad.addColorStop(
            pos,
            "rgb(" + 
              Math.floor(skyColour[0] * col) + "," +
              Math.floor(skyColour[1] * col) + "," +
              Math.floor(skyColour[2] * col) + ")"
         );
     });
     // floating point error can cause problems if we dont set the top
     // at 1
     skyGrad.addColorStop(1,"rgb("+skyColour[0]+","+skyColour[1]+","+skyColour[2]+")");
    
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = skyGrad;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  doFor(starCount, (i) => stars[i].draw());

  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```